# Identification of that red and black bug

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found in France countryside, few hours ago, on a bushlike plant in direct sun light.

There is dozens of individuals, by groups of 5-ish, everywhere on the plant, along aphids, maybe sucking the plant's sap.

Looks like a stink bug, with unexpected colors. Some of them were attached two-by-two by their bottom (mating, probably ?).

Sorry for the bad photo quality.

[image: thumb for scale]
[image: close-up]
[image: she got legs]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like *Graphosoma italicum* (aka *G. lineatum*; it is a stinkbug):

> *Graphosoma italicum* had been regarded as either a subspecies, or a mere synonym to *G. lineatum*.
>
> *G. italicum* can reach a length of 8–12 mm (0.31–0.47 in). The body is almost round, with a large shield. The basic color of the upperside of the body is bright red, with wide black longitudinal stripes. The pronotum has six black bands. The antennae are black. Also the sides of the abdominal segments (connexivum) are red with many small black spots. The legs are black.
> <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphosoma_italicum)</sub>

I think you are right that they are mating. Here is another picture of the species mating:

> [image: Graphosoma italicum mating, attached at the bottom]
> <sub>ibid</sub>

(Despite it saying that the legs are black, they are clearly striped in some specimens, like in your picture.)

It's found in France, according to [Honeyguide](http://www.honeyguide.co.uk/redandblack.htm).